# Why to use OpenMP Single inside of OpenMP parallel block?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

For example:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp single
    QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.length, cuttoff);
}
```

As far as i know `#pragma omp single` makes code serial. Only one process will will execute QuickSort(). Is something wrong with the upper code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. My guess is that there is more code in that block that pre- or post-process the array in parallel, and that only sorting is done by a single thread.

Comment: @Aziz Parallelism inside `QuickSort` is likely achived via nested parallelism and OpenMP tasks/sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This scenario is typically employed by *task parallelism*, where first, you need to create a fixed number of threads and second, you define some *tasks* that are then distributed to these threads by OpenMP runtime. Definition of tasks (via `#pragma omp task` or `#pragma omp section`) must be done within a parallel section. However, there are situations, such as within quicksort, where it does not make sense to define tasks from multiple threads; to define them from a single thread only, you use `#pragma omp single`.

Parallelization of quicksort is not trivial. Additionally to tasking, you also need to execute *partitioning* in parallel at the top levels of recursion. This is in OpenMP achieved via *nested parallelism*.

Consider, e.g., quicksort and 8 cores:

1. You create 8 threads (`#pragma omp parallel`).
2. You invoke `quicksort` by a single thread only (`#pragma omp single`).
3. Within `quicksort`, you invoke `partition`, which splits the single threads into 8 threads via nested parallelism and performs partitioning in parallel.
4. Finally, 2 partitions are created. The single thread now creates 2 tasks (`#pragma omp task`) and invoke itself recursively within them by invoking `quicksort`.
5. OpenMP runtime assigns these 2 tasks to any of 8 available threads, since all are idle now.
6. Now, 2 threads are executing the `quicksort` function.

This case only describes the top level of recursion. At lower levels, you need to care about *load balancing*, since both partitions may be of different sizes. (On the 2nd level, there are two threads executing `partition` concurrently. However, due to generally different sizes of both partitions, you, e.g., split the 1st thread into 3 threads and the 2nd thread into 5 threads to utilize all 8 cores. Basically you want all these cores to be utilized as much as possible, which is quite a challenge for multithreaded quicksort developers.)

Efficient implementation will also employ *tail call optimization*, where only 1 task will be created instead of 2; it saves a lot of stack space and avoid many `call` instructions. Below some threshold, you then switch to sequential quicksort (or rather to some combination of quicksort, insertion sort, and heapsort, for instance).

---

For illustration, this is the trivial implementation of parallel quicksort with OpenMP for sorting an array of integers:

```
void par_qs_rec(int* a, long lo, long hi) {
   if (lo < hi) {
      long p = partition(a, lo, hi);
      #pragma omp task
      par_qs_rec(a, lo, p - 1);
      #pragma omp task
      par_qs_rec(a, p + 1, hi);
   }
}

void par_qs(int* a, long lo, long hi) {
   #pragma omp parallel 
   {
      #pragma omp single
      par_qs_rec(a, lo, hi); // (1)
   }
}
```

What would happen if there was no `#pragma omp single`, i.e., if initial `par_qs_rec` would be invoked by all threads at `(1)`?